# NodeJS - data types, variables, control structures, iterations

Tags: node.js

I am a beginner learning NodeJS. I am sure that the scripting language has its own  data types, variables, control structures, iterations structures etc. But I am not able to find any documentation regarding the same?

Please provide some references of the same.

::EDIT::

JS has functionality till now to run in browsers and there are specific functionality that could be achieved.

How can I write a standalone program that would make a user to input a date in **mm/dd/yyyy** format using NodeJS? Like in browser side we use to say -

```
val = window.prompt('Enter a Date in MM/DD/YYYY format!','');
```

Is there a way I can write the same code in NodeJS without running it in a browser? Also then all JS browser side functionality cannot be used in NodeJS - please clarify.

Comment: Are you searching for JavaScript stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write Node.js servers using JavaScript. So you need to look up the JavaScript documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's all JavaScript, but what you really need is Node's API documentation.

http://nodejs.org/api/documentation.html

As for getting started, looking at some [example code](http://www.nodebits.org/tags/sample-app) is always a good move.